# Grafana templates with OpenTSDB

Tags: grafana, opentsdb

It seems like the documentation for templating in Grafana on OpenTSDB is rather cursory.  I'm having a hard time setting up even a basic template, and some pointers would be appreciated.  I have some simple metrics going into OpenTSDB and I'm trying to create a template.  So, here's a sample metric and its associated tags:

```
disk.free.percent
  -- location
    -- Seattle
    -- Omaha
  -- servertype
    -- web
    -- db
  -- host
    -- web01
    -- web02
    -- db01
    -- db01
disk.free.gb
  (Repeat tags/values)
```

Ideally, what's I'm hoping to create is 4 dropdowns:

1. Selection between disk.free.percent and disk.free.gb
2. Selection of individual hosts
3. Selection between locations
4. Selection between servertypes

But, I'm having trouble with just a second step.  I have no problem getting the first menu using the following in the template settings:

```
Name:  fs
Type:  Query
Data Source:  MyTesterOTSD
Query:  metrics(fs)
```

With those settings, the preview of values works great and I can use $fs as a metric name to create graphs.  Excellent.  However, I'm having all sorts of problems with the next step.  I created a new variable with the following settings:

```
Name:  hosts
Type:  Query
Data Source:  MyTesterOTSD
Query:  $fs
Tags query:  tag_names(fs)
Tag values query:  tag_value(fs, host)
```

This does create a dropdown, but it only contains "None".  Apparently, I'm not catching the vision here.  I've tried variations-- $fs within the tags queries, etc.  How do I do this?  And is there a straightforward way to add in (3) and (4)?  Thank you.